# Generating incremental data for a column

Tags: sql-server

I need to generate PIN numbers in a particular order for about 400 records in the format below. I therefore need an update statement to change the existing pin numbers under PIN column to follow the format below

Table name: Citizen

```
Firstname       Lastname    PIN        Address  Age    other columns....
John             Smith      4311      20001     19
Andrew           Evans      4312      363252    30
Bill             Towny      4313      63322     67
Dame             Beaut      4314      34222     34
```

essentially need to create Pin numbers with increment of 1.....4311, 4312, 4313, 4314

Thanks

_______________________SCRIPT BELOW______________

Below is my script

```
 WITH PIN_NO
AS
(
SELECT 4310 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Firstname, Lastname) NEW_PIN, *
FROM [dbo].[C3MDMRevsBens]
)

UPDATE PIN_NO
SET   [Account Reference Number]  = RIGHT('0' + CAST(NEW_PIN AS    
VARCHAR (10)),5)
```

When I ran a query to select it in ascending order

```
select * from [dbo].[C3MDMRevsBens] order by [Account Reference Number]
```

It starts with

```
 00000
 00001
 00002
 00003
 00004
```

It is a VARCHAR(255) column

Comment: [Let me google that for you](https://www.google.pl/search?q=generate_series+sql+server&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=YbnSV_bNBs6v8wej_4HgBQ)

Comment: We can generate PIN numbers but how do we find that particular 400 records in your citizen table

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question but what I will say is there are already random pin numbers in the PIN column, all I want is ..starting from record 1, I want them to have PIN number starting 4311, record 2 will have pin number 4312...Rec 3 to have PIN 4313...essentially Pin numbers with increment of 1.....4311, 4312, 4313

Comment: If you are not already using an [Identity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) for your PK then use it here, you can specify the starting number when you create it (@ 4311)

Comment: Kindly advice, whats the script for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
Note: You didn't mentioned any order to update the PIN so i'm ordering by Firstname and Lastname.

```
;WITH PIN_NO
AS
(
    SELECT 4310 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Firstname, Lastname ) NEW_PIN, *
    FROM Citizen
)

UPDATE PIN_NO
SET  PIN = RIGHT('0' + CAST(NEW_PIN AS VARCHAR(10)),5)
```

Comment: I ran the script ...and then using a select statement, I ordered PIN. As opposed to the format I wanted it, the records now starts with 10000
100000
100001
100002
100003
100004
100005
100006
100007
100008
100009
10001
100010
100011
100012
100013
100014
100015
100016
100017
100018
100019
10002
100020
100021
100022
100023
100024
100025
100026
100027
100028
100029
10003
100030
100031
100032
100033
100034
100035
100036

Comment: Is your PIN column varchar() ?

Comment: I have updated the query.Check if this works for you.

Comment: change 9999 to 4310. ROW_NUMBER() will be 1 to N so to get the 4311, 4312...incremented by 1 number you want you need to start at 4310 not 9999

Comment: @Matt I wrote the query like that before but according to optimisteve's latest comment, I think he wants no. to be generated from 10000

Comment: @SagarShelke no his comment clearly states "as **opposed** to the format I wanted it, the records now start with 100000" he is stating that the 100001 100002 is the results of your query and it is NOT what he wants

Comment: @Matt I changed my query after his comment and not before it. Anyways its not a big deal to change it to start from expected no.

Comment: What I want is for records to start from 4310 incrementally up to the last record. But using your query, it doesn't seem to be doing that, rather, the numbers computed are what I showed above. please advice further

Comment: @SagarShelke If I need the numbers to be generated in the format 04310, 04311, 04312, what part of the script needs modification. I ammened the 'CAST(NEW_PIN AS VARCHAR(10))' to CAST(NEW_PIN AS NVARCHAR(10))' this doesn't seem to make a difference. All I want to do is keep leading zero. many thanks

Comment: @optimisteve changed query to append leading zero. If this works for you please accept the answer.

Comment: @SagarShelke, sure will do once that happens. I ran the script and noticed the minimum number is 00000 and there are instances where same numbers are generated. I would expect it to have started from 4310. Kindly help pls

Comment: @optimisteve can you post your whole query because whatever query I have provided you will not generate duplicates as well it doesn't start with no. 00000. There must me something else you must be doing.

Comment: @SagarShelke.....I have done that..see below my original post or below your script